# Slickgrid cell colors lost on scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

I'm using a slickgrid to display certain values. Upon satisfying a particular condition, i'm highlighting the cells with yellow color using the statement

```
$($('.grid-canvas').children()[args.row].children[args.cell]).context.style.background = "yellow";
```

I'm holding this slickgrid under a `<div>`.
Now as the number of rows increase, a scrollbar appears within the `<div>`.
As i scroll down to reach the last row and then scroll back up to the first row, the cell colors that were initially there in the cells of the top rows are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Because Slickgrid will redraw the grid upon scrolling (instead of storing all data in DOM tree), so what you set in DOM will be reset, we have to use the API of Slickgrid to set background at specific row, column : `grid.setCellCssStyles(key, hash)`

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#setCellCssStyles

you can look demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/n58Cq/90/

Comment: Thank you nhabuiduc. Now i have to achieve a scenario where i have to highlight the cell that i click on. I'm again doing that using 
`$($('.grid-canvas').children()[args.row].children[args.cell]).context.style.background = "red"` which is written inside the onclick function. If the cell is already highlighted, i'm removing the color on click. Now upon scrolling down and going back up, the colours are lost.